# Snapshot returned is of wrong type from type declared in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I retrieve a snapshot from a firebase db in a flutter StreamBuilder but the snapshot is of a different type than the StreamBuilder.

I expect to get stream of the type "Events" as defined by the Events model seen below:

```
class Events {
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  Events({
    this.eventName,
    this.eventStartTime,
    this.eventDuration,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventDescription,
    this.userId,
    this.companyId,
  });

  Events copyWith({
    String? eventName,
    DateTime? eventStartTime,
    String? eventDuration,
    DateTime? eventDate,
    String? eventDescription,
    String? userId,
    String? companyId,
  }) {
    return Events(
      eventName: eventName ?? this.eventName,
      eventStartTime: eventStartTime ?? this.eventStartTime,
      eventDuration: eventDuration ?? this.eventDuration,
      eventDate: eventDate ?? this.eventDate,
      eventDescription: eventDescription ?? this.eventDescription,
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
    );
  }
}
```

I have a riverpod 2.0 notifier class that contains a method, **fromFirestore**, that gets the data from firestore...I think. Here is the code of this Notifier class:

```
class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));
  EventsNotifier();

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(   // Return the initial state
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;
 

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        userId = firestore['agentId'],
        companyId = firestore['agencyId'];

  }
}
```

In the StreamBuilder, I cast the data as **Events** to match the data I should be getting from the db. Here is the StreamBuilder code:

```
StreamBuilder<Events>(
            stream: _db.collection('users').doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
              .collection('event')
              .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
              .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                    .snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(document.data()))
              .toList()),
            builder: (context, eventsSnapShot) {
              if (eventsSnapShot.hasData) {
                eventDoc = eventsSnapShot.data;
                //print('eventDoc: ' + eventDoc.toString());
                return _buildTableCalendar(eventsSnapShot.data as List<Events>?);
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
```

In the StreamBuilder code the line a red line error marker under it.

```
snapshot.docs.map((document) => EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(document.data())).toList()),
```

The error is this:

**The return type 'List< EventsNotifier >' isn't a 'Events', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure
(new) EventsNotifier EventsNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)**

So, the snapshot data is cast as a list of EventNotifier. I don't understand how this can be because the EventsNotifier is cast as Events as seen below.

```
class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You should choose to use either a StreamNotifier[Provider], or a StreamBuilder.  Not both at the same time.